# Calculate the most common value from a php array

Tags: php

I am trying to get the most common hour an array.
The foreach loop is to split the values and get an array only with hours

```
 foreach ($times as $k => $v) {
    $avtime[$k] = explode("T", $v);
    $avtimeb[$k] = $avtime[$k][1];
    foreach ($avtimeb as $kb => $vb) {
        $avtimec[$kb] = explode(":", $vb);
        $avtimed[$kb] = $avtimec[$kb][0];
    }
}
```

and `print_r($avtimed);` generates the below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08
    [1] => 08
    [2] => 08
    [3] => 08
    [4] => 09
    [5] => 09
    [6] => 08
    [7] => 08
    [8] => 08
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 09
    [11] => 09
    [12] => 10
    [13] => 11
    [14] => 07
    [15] => 08
    [16] => 13
    [17] => 07
    [18] => 08
    [19] => 08
    [20] => 08
    [21] => 09
    [22] => 09
    [23] => 09
    [24] => 09
)
```

Now i need to get the most common value from the above.

Comment: Did you try something before asking? If so, put the code you're working on :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626785/php-most-frequent-value-in-array

Comment: Where did this data come from?  If it's from a database then it's probably better to get the database to work this out for you.

Comment: Its an array of timmings of the posts extracted from facebook api.

Comment: `array_count_values(array_map(function($value) { return substr(11,2, $value); }));` is a good starting point; then you can sort the resulting array

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Using an external array you can store the similar hour. then browse the array for getting the common hour.

**Technique**

```
$out = array(); 
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $part = explode("T", $value);
    $hour = explode(":", $part[1]);
    $out[$hour[0]] = $hour[0];
}

print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Final one is:

```
foreach ($times as $k => $v) {
    $avtime[$k] = explode("T", $v);
    $avtimeb[$k] = $avtime[$k][1];
    foreach ($avtimeb as $kb => $vb) {
        $avtimec[$kb] = explode(":", $vb);
        $avtimed[$kb] = $avtimec[$kb][0];
    }
}
$count = array_count_values($avtimed);
arsort($count); 
$keys = array_keys($count);
echo "The most occuring value is $keys[0] and the second one is $keys[1]";
```

Thanks all for help.