# Get the most listed values from all JSONs

Tags: php, json

I have multiple JSON strings, which are stored in my database.

Here are 3 example of how they could look like:

**Example 1**

```
{
    "request": {
        "city": "Chicago",
        "country": "USA",
        "gender": "m"
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
{
    "request": {
        "city": "Chicago",
        "country": "USA",
        "gender": "f",
        "role": "admin"
    }
}
```

**Example 3**

```
{
    "request": {
        "city": "Paris",
        "country": "France",
        "gender": "m",
        "language": "French",
        "role": "admin"
    }
}
```

I would like to compare all JSONs with each other and create a new JSON with the **most listed values**. This is how the result should be:

**Result**

```
{
    "request": {
        "city": "Chicago",
        "country": "USA",
        "gender": "m",
        "role": "admin"
    }
}
```

**Why?**

Because we had 3 JSONS and

- `Chicago` appeared 2x
- `USA` appeared 2x
- `m` appeard 2x
- `admin` appeared 2x

How can I get that JSON that I need?

**PS:** I don't need a finished code. It's enough if someone could explain me HOW I could do it.

Comment: This is not average, this is the max. You want the item that appeared the most/max number of times.

Comment: @NawedKhan oh sorry, you are right! The most listed values should be created in the new JSON.

Comment: See [HOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626785/php-most-frequent-value-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a array for every JSON key (role, gender, city ...)

Then when I parse the JSON, I would add the values to the specific array.

In the end just count the most used values in the array and output the value.

```
$city = ["Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Florida", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles"];

$count = array_count_values($city);

arsort($count); 

$mostUsedCity = key($count); 

echo $mostUsedCity;
```

Output: Los Angeles

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So that means I have to create arrays for all columns first?

Comment: Yeah correct. That would be my way to approach it. An array for city, country, gender.. .and in the end get the most used value for each and create a new JSON from it. Would be a good way to create a function for that.

Comment: Okay that sounds to be a good way. Great, thank you for your help!

Comment: @RezaSaadati No problem, I will think about it if I see another way to approach this prob